# Problemas para autenticar no servidor Report Service 2014 via C# aplicação MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, relatório

Estou com um problema para conectar no servidor de Report Service 2014 via C# de um projeto MVC4:

Cenário:

- Foi montado um Servidor Report Service 2014 que terá inúmeros relatórios, devido ao cliente ter inúmeras bases SQL Server espalhados pelo estado de SP. a Solução mais viável foi essa pois no Report Server temos como adicionar varias conexões tals (DataSources).

ate aqui ok.

Problema:

- Tem uma aplicação MVC5 que terá uma lista destes relatórios, onde o Cliente (usuário) ira abrir tals para ver. A questão é "Não consigo conectar no Servidor de Report Service", o erro é:

  O servidor remoto retornou um erro: `(401) Não Autorizado.`

  Ex: Código

  ```
  public FileContentResult teste()
  {
      NetworkCredential Credential = new NetworkCredential("/USER/", "/PASS/");
      WebClient client = new WebClient();
      client.Credentials = Credential;

      string reportURL = "http://localhost/report/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Relatorios/ColaboradoresRpt&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=pdf";
      return File(client.DownloadData(reportURL), "application/pdf");
  }
  ```

Comment: [Eu tive um problema anteriormente a baixar um report](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146449). Verifique se nao está na mesma situacao

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente o `WebClient` não está passando as credenciais para o Report Service.

No seu lugar, eu tentaria o acesso usando [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) com [`HttpClientHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclienthandler%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) para especificar com maior minúcia os dados da autenticação.

No exemplo abaixo, o envio do cabeçalho de autenticação atende bem o padrão REST. Como não conheço bem o protocolo de autenticação do Report Service, diria que o padrão é parecido, mas algum ajuste pode ser necessário:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
    var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Usuario:Senha");
    var header = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
               "Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = header;

    var result = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(uri);
}
```