# Como é que posso fazer Download de um report? Problema de credênciais

Tags: c#, autenticação, reporting-services

Eu estou a tentar fazer download de um report (SSRS). Mais especificamente eu quero guarda-lo numa pasta para o poder imprimir.

Acontece que em desenvolvimento eu não tenho quaisquer problemas em fazer download do report. Mas, no minimo tenho que especificar que quero usar as credenciais por omissão:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
}
```

Contudo quando tento publicar a aplicação no servidor IIS sou obrigado a especificar as credênciais (username, password), senão obtenho um Erro `403 Forbidden` ou `401 Unauthorized`:

```
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

Na minha perspectiva o utilizador da Application Pool do IIS deveria ter permissões suficientes para fazer download do report, uma vez que eu também tenho.

Este é o meu código atual, sem a parte de imprimir.

```
public string Print(string reportUri, string printerName)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var path = Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetTempFileName(), "pdf");

        client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        client.DownloadFile(reportUri, path);

        return path;
    }
}
```

O que tenho que fazer para fazer download do report em produção, sem especificar as credenciais?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O meu servidor de reports e o servidor de aplicação não eram o mesmo. (Acho) que por este motivo o utilizador de IIS não tinha permissões para ler o report.

A solução foi usar um utilizador comum aos dois servidores (pois eles estão no mesmo dominio) e que tivesse acesso de leitura aos reports. É necessário também configurar o utilizador da application pool para usar esse mesmo utilizador.